# Setter not changing the data from a vector within a class

Tags: c++, qt, class, vector, setter

In my program, I have a class that holds a vector of type integer. It is used to store distances. I have a function, that when called, should set values in the vector to 0's. (used for initializing). But when I go to check the size of the vector, it still says the vector is empty.

I have created multiple functions that check whether the vector is adding any elements, and it is not. I have a function, that within main, I call to see if the vector is empty, and it returns 0 (the vector has 0 elements in it).

```
int MLB::getDistanceSize()
{
    return distances.size();
}

void MLB::setInitialDistances(int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        this->distances.push_back(0);
    }
}
```

```
class MLB
{
public:
    //constructor
    MLB();
    ~MLB();

    int getDistanceSize();
    void setInitialDistances(int size);

private:
    vector<int> distances;
};
```

The input file is a csv file with each line consisting of:

stadium1,stadium2,distance

so sample input file is:

```
AT&T Park,Safeco Field,680
AT&T Park,Oakland–Alameda County Coliseum,50
Angel Stadium,Petco Park,110
Angel Stadium,Dodger Stadium,50
Busch Stadium,Minute Maid Park,680
Busch Stadium,Great American Ball Park,310
Busch Stadium,Target Field,465
Busch Stadium,Kauffman Stadium,235
```

etc...

I am using qt, and this is where I am calling the functions themselves. All information is stored into a map, and the other getters work perfectly fine. Sorry for making this a lot more confusing than the problem really is, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// key and value, key is the team name, value is the MLB stadium information
struct entry
{
    string key;
    MLB value;
};

class Map
{
    public:
        //Public default constructor
        Map();

        //Public default destructor
        ~Map();

        // returns entry of the map
        entry atIndex(int index);

        // Inserts a key and its value using linear algorithm
        void insert(const string& theKey, const MLB& value);

    private:

    vector<entry> thisTable;
    int currentSize;    //Integer variable for current size
};
```

functions for Map:

```
Map::Map()
{
    currentSize = 0;
}

Map::~Map()
{
}

void Map::insert(const string& theKey, const MLB& value)
{
    entry thisEntry;
    thisEntry.key = theKey;
    thisEntry.value = value;

    thisTable.push_back(thisEntry);

    currentSize+=1;
}

entry Map::atIndex(int index)
{
    return thisTable.at(index);
}
```

```
//mainwindow constructor
mainWindow::mainWindow()
{

    //Reads in input from first csv file, all works fine all data stored and can access it

    string iStadium1;
    string iStadium2;
    string iDistance;
    string previous;
    int distance;
    int index1;
    int index2;
    bool found;

    ifstream csvFile2;
    csvFile2.open("inputDistance.csv");

    getline(csvFile2, iStadium1, ',');
    while(!csvFile2.eof())
    {
        index1 = 0;
        found = false;
        while(!found)
        {
            if(thisMap.atIndex(index1).value.getStadiumName() == iStadium1)
            {
                thisMap.atIndex(index1).value.setInitialDistances(thisMap.mapSize());
                cout << "Distance Size Test 1: " << thisMap.atIndex(index1).value.getDistanceSize() << endl;
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                index1++;
            }
        }

        previous = iStadium1;

        while(iStadium1 == previous)
        {
            getline(csvFile2, iStadium2, ',');
            getline(csvFile2, iDistance, '\n');
            distance = stoi(iDistance);

            index2 = 0;
            found = false;

            while(!found)
            {
                if(thisMap.atIndex(index2).value.getStadiumName() == iStadium2)
                {
                    found = true;
                    cout << "Distance Size Test 2: " << thisMap.atIndex(index1).value.getDistanceSize() << endl;
                    // crashes here. Index out of bounds, size is 0 for some reason
                    thisMap.atIndex(index1).value.setDistance(index2, distance);
                }
                else
                {
                    index2++;
                }
            }
            getline(csvFile2, iStadium1, ',');
        }
    }

    csvFile2.close();
}
```

I expect the vector to hold 30 slots (assuming the desired size passed into the function is 30) of value 0, rather than having an empty vector.

Comment: Yes, that's what the code you have posted will do. So the error you see is somewhere else in your code. You need to post more code, particularly the part where you check the size of the vector. Very often (especially with newbies) the bug isn't where they think it is.

Comment: I took your code and put it online, http://cpp.sh/6d7aa. As you can see it works correctly.

Comment: How are you creating this object and inspecting the vector afterwards?

Comment: the code does what you expected it does, in my answer and in the link provided. WHat is the problem ?

Comment: @john I updated my code with where I call the function itself. I am using qt, and it may be a little complicated as I am reading from a csv file to store all the inputs. If you could take a look at that, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @OscarLopez I would guess that you are dealing with two different objects. So when you call `thisMap.atIndex(index1).value` you don't get the same object back each time.

Comment: @John it is strange to me, because when I call thisMap.atIndex(index1).value.getStadiumName(), it gives me the stadium name correctly. Which means I am on the right object, but it won't save the information in the vector. The vector is the only one that wont save

Comment: @OscarLopez Would need to see how `thisMap` and `atIndex` are defined.

Comment: @OscarLopez That doesn't prove anything. You are getting copies of your objects, so the stadium name copies correctly, but when you change something it only changes that particular copy, not the copy you get the next time you call `atIndex`.

Comment: @OscarLopez If you post the code for `atIndex` I hope this can be cleared up quickly.

Comment: @OscarLopez Right, change to this `entry& Map::atIndex(int index)
{
    return thisTable.at(index);
}`

Comment: @john I updated my code for atIndex

Comment: @OscarLopez As I thought, `atIndex` does not return the entry in your map, it returns a **copy** of the entry in your map. Change it to return a reference (see two comments above).

Comment: @john I think he same, and put an example in my answer

Comment: @john It works like a charm now. Thank you so much! I have been at it for about 6 hours now and decided to just ask on here.

Comment: @OscarLopez it's a very confusing issue the first time you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question works as expected after adding constructor and destructor (doing both nothing) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MLB
{
public:
    //constructor
    MLB();
    ~MLB();

    int getDistanceSize();
    void setInitialDistances(int size);

private:
    vector<int> distances;
};

int MLB::getDistanceSize()
{
    return distances.size();
}

void MLB::setInitialDistances(int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        this->distances.push_back(0);
    }
}

MLB::MLB() {
}

MLB::~MLB() {
}


int main()
{
  MLB mlb;

  mlb.setInitialDistances(30);
  cout << mlb.getDistanceSize() << endl;
}

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ d.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
30
```

the vector is not empty but contains 30 times 0

---

if `thisMap.atIndex(index1).value.setDistance(index2, distance);` does nothing this is probably because *atIndex(index1)* returns a copy rather than a reference, so you modify a copy and the original is unchanged

For instance :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class C {
  public:
    vector<int> getv() { return v; } // return a copy
    vector<int> & getvref() { return v; } // return the ref to the vector, not a copy
    int len() { return v.size(); }

  private:
    vector<int> v;
};

int main()
{
  C c;

  c.getv().push_back(0); // modify a copy of v
  cout << c.len() << endl;

  c.getvref().push_back(0); // modify v
  cout << c.len() << endl;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ vv.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0
1
```

---

you edited you question and this is what I supposed :

```
entry Map::atIndex(int index)
{
    return thisTable.at(index);
}
```

return a copy, must be

```
entry & Map::atIndex(int index)
{
    return thisTable.at(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately I had left out the constructor and destructor from my question because I thought it wouldn't be necessary for a question like this, but I do have them in my program. It still does not save the 30 values of 0. I updated my question with where I call it, hope you can still take a look at that and find my error there!

Comment: @OscarLopez I updated my answer, I think _atIndex()_ return a copy of the element rather than a reference to

Comment: @OscarLopez I edited my answer to add an example to explain

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @OscarLopez probably you will need 2 definition,s the current (adding the reference), and an other one in the case const returnint a const reference